# Remove duplicates based on only 1 column

Tags: tableau-api

My data is in the following format:

```
rep_id  user_id  other non-duplicated data
1       1        ...
1       2        ...
2       3        ...
3       4        ...
3       5        ...
```

I am trying to achieve a column for `deduped_rep` with 0/1 such that only first rep id across the associated users has a 1 and rest have 0.

Expected result:

```
rep_id  user_id  deduped_rep
1       1        1
1       2        0
2       3        1
3       4        1
3       5        0
```

For reference, in Excel, I would use the following formula: 
`IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($A$2:$A2=A2))>1,0,1)`

I know there is the FIXED() LoD calculation http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/removing-duplicate-data-with-lod-calculations, but I only see use cases of it deduplicating based on another column. However, mine are distinct.

Comment: sometimes you're forced to handle dups at the visualization layer, but in general, things work out better if you can filter out duplicates early on - in data prep, or maybe in an extract filter

Comment: @AlexBlakemore , there are no actual duplicates though. reps to users is a 1 to many relationship. But when data blending from two data sources, I am not allowed to use count distinct hence the de-duplication flag request

Comment: Then to fully specify your problem, you need to define "first". Is that the copy with the lowest user_id? Also, is this the primary data source? or a secondary data source?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore "first" can be based on registration_date (this is when the user creates an account). This data is the primary source, taking some metrics from a secondary source causes the above mentioned issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a field **first_reg_date_per_rep_id** as

```
{ fixed rep_id : min(registration_date) }
```

The define a field **is_first_reg_date?** as

```
registration_date = first_reg_date_per_rep_id
```

You can use that last Boolean field to distinguish the first record for each rep_id from later ones

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select 
    rep_id,
    user_id,
    row_number() over(partition by rep_id order by rep_id,user_id) deduped_rep
from 
    table
```